# How to identity which users can perform certain actions for specific resource with ARN in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

As titled. I can only test on a specific account only with IAM Policy Simulator and the IAM Policy Simulator is not quite working at all. I was testing with a user group with AWS S3 full access policy and test against all 12x S3 actions, all denied.

Comment: Hi, where can be more things than IAM that blocks the access to s3. There can be bucket policies and SCPs. But I don't fully understand your question. Do you want to know if a user have access to a resource by reading the arn of the resource?

Comment: There is no such way. You have to develop your own custom solution for that, which will be extremely difficult.